# Get id from each li

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get the `id` of dynamic `li` elements?

```
<ul id="3" class="test">
    <li id="2">aca2</li>
    <li id="1">aca</li>
  </ul>
```

```js
$('.test').each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(e){
        alert(this.id); //returns 3
    });
});
```

Comment: **1.** No need of `each` to bind event. Just use `$('.test li').on('click', function() { alert(this.id); });`

Comment: `$('.test').each()` calls the function for each element matching the `.test` selector, which is the `<ul>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `each()` as you can bind the event directly to all child `li` elements of `.test`. Try this:

```
$('.test li').on('click', function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Or if the `li` elements are dynamically appended you can use a delegated event handler:

```
$('.test').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

> what if I want to get input field value inside li

```
$('.test').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    alert($(this).find('input').val());
});
```

Comment: what if I want to get `input` field value inside `li`?

Comment: @mokiSRB Use `$(this).find('input').val()` This will give the value of the first `<input>` inside the clicked `<li>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen at click event using a selector. By this way you can also change dinamically the contents of the ul (ie: add/remove items) without affecting his behavior.

```
$('.test').on('click', 'li', function(event){
    alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adael/kf03rfg6/1/

Comment: You don't need the `($(event.target).is('li')` test, jQuery handles that for you and the event target you likely expect will be available as `this` in the callback function: https://jsfiddle.net/kf03rfg6/2/

Comment: You have been quick!, I'm updating it already while you were comenting. Thanks for the hint anyway!